# SOQL to fetch field on Order from Transaction

Tags: soql, query

I am trying to query a text field DealName__c on the Order from Transaction. Transaction is lookup relationship to contract and contract is having one to many relationship to Order. How to get text field on Order from transaction using single SOQL?

Comment: What are you expecting as a result? Since many `Transaction` records could  correspond to a given `Order`, it is hard to understand what behavior you hope to achieve.

Comment: @AdrianLarson
Select Id, Status, contract__r.Id From Transaction --> will give me records from transaction
Suppose if I want to get the DealName__c which is on order using the above query how to incorporate the relationship? As contract is lookup to transaction and contract is lookup to order. How to write the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't do it in one query. The way you describe the objects, `Transaction` and `Order` seem to be siblings (objects sharing the same parent).

Because there is a 1-N relationship from `Contract` to `Order`, SoQL has no way of knowing which of the Order records needs to pull the `DealName__c` field from.

Below is one example of what you could do to find all the `Order` records for the `Contract` that this `Transaction` belongs to (there are many more ways to solve that problem, depending on your actual needs):

```
//Assuming myRecord is a variable that contains the ID of an existing Transaction Record
Transaction tran = [select Id, Contract__c from Transaction where Id = :myRecord Limit 1];

//We assume the Contract__c field is not null, ever. If not, add some validation
Contract cont = [select Id, (Select DealName__c from Orders) where id = :tran.Contract__c limit 1];

//Here goes whatever logic you want to use
for (Order ord : cont.orders) {
  //Do something here with ord.DealName__c
}
```